# Scared of the chance of shirk

Tags: salat, practical-islam, allah, shirk, forgiveness

Around the time when is was between 14-15 years old I admired a anime character I liked his name was escanor a human who got powers of the sun and Had a god complex during the day and was anxious and depressed during the night. He was my favourite character I also played a role play game with my friends when playing I chose to be escanor and had to act like him so I said his lines like “praise the sun “. Or “I’m the pinnacle of al races”
Now 2-3 years later I learned what shirk means and I’m terrified of the chance that I have committed this horrible sin
At the time I did not know about shirk and also had clearly no intent of shirk or worship this character.now I’m 17 and terrified and anxious.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously avoid statements of shirk for any reason. Allah knows if He rejected you for your statement, but considering it was unintentional I personally don't know. But if you've ever committed shirk, either intentionally or not, solution is always to recite the Shahada.